# The relative layout leaving spaces where it should not?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am using a relative layout to align the image at the bottom but the image is giving away some margin at the top and at the bottom. My code is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/back" >
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me out with this. Thank you

I tried using Fllo answer and i am attaching the screenshot

[image: there is a space below the image where as it should go to the bottom]

I am uploading the png

[image]

Comment: Why do you need an outer LinearLayout? to waste performances?!

Comment: Try to remove the layout_alignParentTop/Bottom from the ImageView and put layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: @Omar it is not working

Comment: @Rajeev I didnt understand your question before. Try Fllo answer

Comment: Please see the question update, i have added a screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code for Image View from:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

To:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"` is the solution of your problem.

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Then you should change your accepted answer to that help you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` at the same time. You don't need a parent `LinearLayout` but you need to set your `RelativeLayout` height to `match_parent`. Try as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="FIT_XY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As *Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille* suggested, I think it's the right way to avoid deformation with your image. The attribute [`scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) according to the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#FILL) is to:

> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src

It's not a bad idea.

Comment: @Filo the image is coming at the bottom but their is some space at the bottom i guess the image is vertically aligned to the center of the layout

Comment: @Rajeev well, your image is a 9-patch? Did you look at your image to see if the space is into it? However you can set padding and margin to 0 even if I think there is neither padding nor margin inside the layout..

Comment: @Filo please check the screenshot after i tried your answer. No the image is not 9-patch

Comment: Can you post your image separately please? (Not inside your app, the file .jpg or .png..)

Comment: You add your image dynamically? If yes post the code please.

Comment: @Filo No i am doing it through xml only please check the image

Comment: @Filo Same issue when a plane image is used

Comment: Then, I see only one remain issue: it might be the size: your image seems to big in width and not in height. Try to resize it. (Last chance, because I don't see anything else wrong, sorry..)

Comment: So better to accept it rather than mine, *Rushabh Patel* found the way. Accept it and up vote mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

try changing this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

to

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/back" >
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         >
       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/compare1footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is already the case.. And no change. Please before posting an answer, read the others.